# How to see variable content in debuging Eclipse PyDev?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I used to have this ability but for some reason it is gone.

When debugging I used to hover over variable and see its content.. how do I restore this ability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just checked it here and it's working for me... In the latest versions, some changes were done to the hover, so, make sure you have it properly configured to show the debug hover.

I.e.: in preferences > pydev > editor > hover

If you have "combine hovers" selected and the "pydev debug hover" checked and the "show variables values while debugging" checked (as image below) it should work.

[image]